# Embed an image in a TreeNode

Tags: c#, treeview, treenode

How to embed a full-size image to a TreeNode?

The goal is to display detailed log file, where each node represents window caption and its subnodes contain keylog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following pattern to add images to the `TreeView` image list.

```
ImageList treeList = new ImageList();
treeList.Images.Add("imageKey", myImage);
```

Then to set an image to a node use

```
myNode.ImageKey = "imageKey";
```

Comment: It will add the icon to the node. The goal is to display screenshots as well as text in the node

Comment: If you use the above, in combination with `myNode.Text`, it will display both image and text.

Comment: Sure, it does. Is it possible to change the icon size? Now it's 16x16, is there a way to display image unresized?

Comment: `treeList.ImageSize = New Size(32, 32)`. If the image appears disfigured try playing around with `treeList.ColorDepth`

Answer (score 1):

Try this function :

```
 private void FillTreeView()
{
    // Load the images in an ImageList.
    ImageList myImageList = new ImageList();
    myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile("1.gif"));
    myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile("2.gif"));
    myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile("3.gif"));
    myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile("4.gif"));
    myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile("5.gif"));
    myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile("6.gif"));
    myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile("7.gif"));

    // Assign the ImageList to the TreeView.
    myTreeView.ImageList = myImageList;

    // Set the TreeView control's default image and selected image indexes.
    myTreeView.ImageIndex = 0;
    myTreeView.SelectedImageIndex = 1;

    /* Set the index of image from the 
    ImageList for selected and unselected tree nodes.*/ 
    this.rootImageIndex = 2;
    this.selectedCustomerImageIndex = 3;
    this.unselectedCustomerImageIndex = 4;
    this.selectedOrderImageIndex = 5;
    this.unselectedOrderImageIndex = 6;

    // Create the root tree node.
    TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode("TheList");
    rootNode.ImageIndex = rootImageIndex;
    rootNode.SelectedImageIndex = rootImageIndex;

    // Add a main root tree node.
    myTreeView.Nodes.Add(rootNode);

    // Add a root tree node for each Customer object in the ArrayList. 
    foreach(Customer myCustomer in customerArray)
    {
        // Add a child tree node for each Order object. 
        int countIndex=0;
        TreeNode[] myTreeNodeArray = new TreeNode[myCustomer.CustomerOrders.Count];
        foreach(Order myOrder in myCustomer.CustomerOrders)
        {
            // Add the Order tree node to the array.
            myTreeNodeArray[countIndex] = new TreeNode(myOrder.OrderID,
              unselectedOrderImageIndex, selectedOrderImageIndex);
            countIndex++;
        }
        // Add the Customer tree node.
        TreeNode customerNode = new TreeNode(myCustomer.CustomerName,
            unselectedCustomerImageIndex, selectedCustomerImageIndex, myTreeNodeArray);
        myTreeView.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(customerNode);
    }
}
```