# How to set an icon for each object in TreeListView

Tags: c#, objectlistview, treelistview

I have some icons which should be displayed in the first column next to the name of RowObject.
Different pictures related to different type of obects.
This part of code creates columns with objects that I need.

```
    this.descriptionTView = new BrightIdeasSoftware.TreeListView();
    this.descriptionTView.CanExpandGetter = x =>
    {
    if ( ( x as ITreeViewItem ).Items != null )
       {
       return ( x as ITreeViewItem ).Items.Length > 0;
       }
    else
       {
       return false;
       }
    };                

    this.descriptionTView.ChildrenGetter = x => ( x as ITreeViewItem ).Items;

    var column1 = new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn( "", "Part0" );
    column1.AspectGetter = x => ( x as ITreeViewItem ).Part0;
    column1.IsEditable = true;

    var column2 = new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn( "", "Part1" );
    column2.AspectGetter = x => ( x as ITreeViewItem ).Part1;
    column1.IsEditable = true;
    column2.IsEditable = true;

    this.descriptionTView.Columns.Add( column1 );
    this.descriptionTView.Columns.Add( column2 );
    private List<ITreeViewItem> itemsList;
    descriptionTView.Roots = itemsList;
```

Comment: I believe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12728738/3521452) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Would you please add further details and post a snippet of your code? It's not possible to help you with no information.

Comment: In ObjectListView we don't use TreeNode or Node we add different objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create and assign an ImageList containing the images you want to use like this for example

```
descriptionTView.SmallImageList = imageList1;
```

Then you can implement an ImageGetter for the desired column

```
column1.ImageGetter = delegate(object rowObject) {
    // decide depending on the rowObject which image to return
    return 0;
};
```

You can also return the name of the image in the list, instead of the index.

You may have to set

```
descriptionTView.OwnerDraw = true;
```

An alternative would be to get the image directly from the row object using the `ImageAspectName`

```
column1.ImageAspectName = "MyImage"; // Assuming your object has a property `public BitMap MyImage;`
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a `ImageList` to your `TreeView`, after that you can set a node's with `ImageKey` attribute.

Comment: I don't use nodes. My objects don't contains ImageKey attribute.